# Simple WHERE clause but keep extracted rows and fill them will null values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which basically looks like this one:

```
Date        |  Criteria
12-04-2016       123
12-05-2016       1234
...
```

Now I want to select those rows with values in the column 'Criteria' within a given range but I want to keep the extracted rows. The extracted rows should get the value 'null' for the column 'Criteria'. So for example, if I want to select the row with 'Criteria = 123' my result should look like this:

```
Date        |  Criteria
12-04-2016       123
12-05-2016       null
```

Currently I am using this query to get the result:

```
SELECT b.date, a.criteria 
FROM (SELECT id, date, criteria FROM ABC WHERE criteria > 100 and criteria < 200) a 
FULL OUTER JOIN ABC b ON a.id = b.id ORDER BY a.criteria
```

Someone told me that full outer joins perform very badly. Plus my table has like 400000 records and the query is used pretty often. So anyone has an idea to speed up my query? Btw I am using the Oracle11g database.

Comment: You want to often run a query that is basically doing a full table scan of a table with 4kk rows every time? Why? What if there are a lot of criterias at one taken date? Will you have many similar dates? Wouldn't it be better to just create an index on date and select distinct date, null union it with select where critera = 123?

Comment: @stee1rat There already is an index on date. I can also use a union, but then I get a united table with many date duplicates, some of them have a real value for the column 'Criteria' and some of them just a null value. How would you remove those duplicates?

Comment: Just use distinct. it really depends on your goals.

Comment: Well, distinct does not work in this case because for one duplicate only the date is the same and not the value for 'Criteria'. So for example if I have the two rows '12-04-2016; 123' and '12-04-2016; null' the row with the null value should be removed. Distinct will keep both of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you just want a `case` expression?

```
SELECT date,
       (case when criteria > 100 and criteria < 200 then criteria end) as criteria
FROM ABC;
```